# Executable Scenarios (BDD) for C++

Tags: c++, bdd

Does anyone know of a BDD framework for C++ that allows the execution of (Gherkin) scenarios such as:

```
Feature: Table support in nbehave
Scenario: a table
  Given a list of people:
    |Name   |Country|
    |Morgan |Sweden |
    |Jimmy  |Sweden |
    |Jimmy  |USA    |
  When I search for people from Sweden
  Then I should find:
    |Name  |Country|
    |Morgan|Sweden |
    |Jimmy |Sweden |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a project called <strike>Cukebins: https://github.com/paoloambrosio/cukebins/wiki/Release-0.2.</strike> I haven't tried it and I don't know how well it works. **Renamed to *Cucumber-CPP* and moved to https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-cpp/**

There's also a discussion with some alternatives here: http://groups.google.com/group/cukes/browse_thread/thread/1f496aba050a22c3/145b871678e2bbbc